Does safe call .? make sure early return null and stop entire following expression?
According to Kotlin documentation here

Such a chain returns null if any of the properties in it is null

My understanding is that, given A?.B?.C, if A is null, then the expression would return null when executing A?. and stop entire following expression, B?.C
But when it is combined with isNullOrEmpty() in the end, seems the following execution is not stoped. And I am confused with why it is different with the case of ABC above?
Take below code as example.

When test is null, I was expecting that the condition of if(test?.getname().isNullOrEmpty()) throw exception of Boolean needed.
Also isNullOrEmpty() cannot be called on null, it needs to be objects like Array<*>? and etc..
But the fact is that "isNullOrEmpty() is executed" is printed.

Hence I would appreciate some explanation about

how to understand the execution of ?.
how come test?.getname().isNullOrEmpty() return as Boolean?

Thanks
fun main() {

    val test : TestNull? = null
    if(test?.getname().isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println("isNullOrEmpty() is executed")         
    } else {
        println("isNullOrEmpty() is not executed")
    }
    
    
    // this won't compile due to Unresolved reference. 
    // Given isNullOrEmpty() cannot be ran on null but object like 
    // Array<*>? 
    if(test?.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        println("isNullOrEmpty() can be ran on null")         
    } else {
        //TODO
    }
    
}


class TestNull {
    fun getname () : String? {
       return "test";
    }
}


Succinctly:
Your assumption in your first sentence is incorrect.
input?.foo() doesn’t stop everything after ?.. It only skips the foo() call when the input is null. The rest of the expression is evaluated as usual, with null as the input for the next part of the chain. This is why you need more ?.s for further calls in the chain.
And isNullOrEmpty() can be called on nullable inputs. It wouldn’t make any sense for it to exist otherwise.

Yeah, I just wanted to point out that while existing answers are correct, they probably don't address the main point of the OP, and the main reason for their confusion. "and stop entire following expression, B?.C" - this is an incorrect assumption, as you explained. Compiler could decide to skip it in some cases, but conceptually, we don't skip it.

A?.B is the same as A.B except that it doesn't throw a NullPointerException if A is null (more accurately, the compiler doesnt even let you compile it to prevent such an exception during runtime), instead the entire expression is null. this can be chained as you already figured out from the documentation.
Let's have a look at how test?.getname().isNullOrEmpty() is evaluated. The first part is test?.getname() which results in any of these:

If test is null then the result is null
If test is not null then getname() is exectued:

If getname() returns null then the result is null
Otherwise the result is a String.



On that result isNullOrEmpty() is now applied. That is an extension function that can be called on a CharSequence. String is a CharSequence so it can also be called on a String. It is declared like this (I omitted some modifiers for brevity's sake):
fun CharSequence?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean

The ? means the CharSequence it is called upon can also be null. Therefore it is perfectly valid to apply isNullOrEmpty to test?.getname(): It returns true when the first part is either null or a String that is empty, like "", false otherwise.
The reason why you cannot compile test?.isNullOrEmpty() is that there is no extension function isNullOrEmpty that can be applied to a TestNull object. Above we used the version that can be applied to CharSequence, and you also already figured out that it can be called on an Array and some other types, but there is no version available that can be applied to TestNull. You can easily create such a function for yourself, though:
fun TestNull?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    return this == null || getname().isNullOrEmpty()
}

You can change the semantics to whatever you want it to be, for this example I decided that it should return true when TestNull's getname() is null or empty.
There is just one thing left: The ? in test?.isNullOrEmpty() actually prevents isNullOrEmpty to be called when test is null. Remember that ?. just returns null and skips the second part when the first part is null. Since null cannot be the condition of an if statement this won't even compile. Just remove the ? and our custom isNullOrEmpty function can take care of the nullability of test.

Like you said, the ?. chain returns null if any of the properties is null. In your test?.getname().isNullOrEmpty() that operator applies to test?.getname(), and that is null, and the resulting expression is null.isNullOrEmpty(), which is true.
isNullOrEmpty is defined for character sequences and arrays, and in your case the result of test?.getname() is String?, so the character sequence call works.
You can also try this with e.g.,
if ((null as String?).isNullOrEmpty()) {
    println("null is null or empty")
}

which also prints its message. The compiler requires the cast to know which extension function to call.
Calling isNullOrEmpty on nulls works because extension functions can have nullable receivers.
Your last code block, if (test?.isNullOrEmpty()) { does not compile because isNullOrEmpty is not defined for TestNull receivers.
You can add an extension function like this:
fun TestNull?.isNullOrEmpty(): Boolean {
    return this == null || this.getname().isNullOrEmpty()
}

Note the ? after the type to indicate the extension function can take a null receiver.
With that, this compiles and prints its message:
if (test.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    println("isNullOrEmpty() can be ran on null")
}


You seem to have typos where you used ?: instead of ?..
